# How to listen for variable change in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have a doubt regarding the implementation of a logic using python. In `printer()`, when the value of `abort` changes in line 10, is there a way for `main()` to know it and immediately break the `while` loop?

**EDIT**:  `abort` becomes `True` if and only if something went wrong.

```
import time

abort = False

def printer():
    global abort
    print("I'm the printer")
    time.sleep(5)
    if somethingiswrong():
        print("I'm aborting here")
        abort = True
    time.sleep(2)
    print("I have aborted")

def main():
    global abort
    while not abort:
        print("In while loop")
        time.sleep(2)
        printer()
        if abort:
            break
        print("Printer killed me")
    print("Quitting")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I mean, the log output is now:

```
> In while loop
> I'm the printer
> I'm aborting here
> I have aborted
> Quitting
```

Is there a more optimized way to achieve an output of:

```
> In while loop
> I'm the printer
> I'm aborting here
> Quitting
```

I'm not an expert and am not familiar with any of the python shortcuts, hacks, tricks, etc. Any help would be great..!!

Comment: What do you need the loop and `abort` for? Your program has a very linear flow.

Comment: There is no way that an assignment to a global can do this. Did you consider throwing an exception?

Comment: You need to start `printer` in another thread for this to work

Comment: @quamrana Throwing an exception where?

Comment: @Mike67, won't another thread increase load?

Comment: @KlausD. this is just an example for a big program. The original program is large and doesn't have a linear flow. I wanna optimise it. So, I'm trying to learn how to do that. That's all :)

Comment: If you want to run the the functions sequentially, call `return` after `abort = True` so `main` knows the print was aborted.

Answer (score 1):

To stop a function (`printer`) to run at some point you could either `return` or `raise` an exception there:

```py
def printer():
    global abort
    print("I'm the printer")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("I'm aborting here")
    abort = True
    if abort:
      return
    ...
```

Comment: That is the current implementation I'm following. Is that the most optimized approach for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use exceptions to control the flow you can:

```py
import time

def printer():
    global abort
    print("I'm the printer")
    time.sleep(5)
    if somethingiswrong():
        print("I'm aborting here")
        raise RuntimeError("I'm aborting here")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("I have aborted")

def main():
    while True:
        print("In while loop")
        time.sleep(2)
        try:
            printer()
        except RuntimeError:
            break
        print("Printer killed me")
    print("Quitting")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output as required